# Gem::LoadError when running Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run Rails Console by executing `rails console` and i am getting that error

```
 /home/ahmed/.rvm/gems/ruby-.2.0@global/gems/bundler-.8.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup': You have already activated spring 1.3.3, but your Gemfile requires spring 1.3.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
  from home/ahmed/.rvm/gems/ruby-.2.0@global/gems/bundler-.8.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
  from /home/ahmed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.8.2/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `setup'
  from /home/ahmed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.8.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/ahmed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from /home/ahmed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from /home/ahmed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/commands.rb:33:in `<module:Spring>'
  from /home/ahmed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/commands.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/ahmed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from /home/ahmed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from /home/ahmed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/server.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/ahmed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
  from /home/ahmed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
  from /home/ahmed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
```

Comment: You can mark code with 4 spaces in front of each line. (I already did it)

Answer (score 13):

I think your machine has multiple spring gem version. I would like to remove spring 1.3.3.

```
$ gem uninstall spring
```

It shows all spring gems on your machine

[image: uninstall spring version like shown on this attached image]

I had similar issue, it solved the issue

Answer (score 3):

change in your application Gemfile

```
gem 'spring'
```

to

```
gem 'spring', "~>1.3.3"
```

and

```
bundle install
bundle update
```

it work for me!

Answer (score 2):

change in your application Gemfile

```
gem 'spring'
```

to

```
gem 'spring', "~>1.3.3"
```

Answer (score 1):

try running bundle update first - that fixed this issue for me

```
   bundle update
```

then

```
  rails console
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try prepending `bundle exec` to your command as it suggest?

```
bundle exec rails console
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and prepending `bundle exec` doesn't fix the problem.