# Trouble starting rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring, controller, gemfile

I am very new to ruby on rails and I'm having this problem with creating a new controller for my "plans" resource:

```
rails generate controller plans
/Users/RentaroSatomi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.8.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in 
'block in setup': You have already activated spring 1.3.3, 
but your Gemfile requires spring 1.3.1. 
Prepending 'bundle exec' to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
```

The error says something about having a wrong spring version, but I really don't know how to fix this.

*EDIT: Solved: [This post solved my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975233/gemloaderror-when-running-rails-console)

Comment: Run `bundle exec rails generate controller plans`; that will fix the issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588674/what-does-bundle-exec-rake-mean for the explanation.

Comment: Already tried that:  'bundle exec rails generate controller plans
/Users/RentaroSatomi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.8.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in block in setup: You have already activated spring 1.3.3, but your Gemfile requires spring 1.3.1. Prepending bundle exec to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)'

Comment: First, stop spring using `bin/spring stop` ; then remove spring `bin/spring binstub --remove --all` ; Finally, do `bundle install` and `bundle exec spring binstub --all`. After this, run your generators.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your Spring gem only. In your console:

```
bundle update spring
```